# Получение позиции курсура мыши в Linux

Tags: linux, golang

Я совсем новичек в Go, кто-нибудь подскажет можно ли получить позицию курсора для Linux систем. Для Windows можно использовать что-то вроде этого: https://github.com/AllenDang/w32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

посмотрите на эти проекты:

1. [X Go Binding (xgb)](https://github.com/BurntSushi/xgb)
2. [A utility library to make use of the X Go Binding easier (xgbutil)](https://github.com/BurntSushi/xgbutil)

возможно, там найдётся искомое.

ссылки взяты со страницы [Go Bindings for Various External APIs](http://go-lang.cat-v.org/library-bindings)

Comment: Судя по всему - здесь есть все, что нужно. Спасибо.

Comment: @grinei, вот список основных библиотек для Go - [один](http://go-lang.cat-v.org/pure-go-libs) и [два](https://github.com/avelino/awesome-go). Советую держать в закладках.